# How to remove substring after occurence of certain characters in a string?

Tags: c#

I have the requirement as follows:

```
input => "Employee.Addresses[].Address.City"
output => "Empolyee.Addresses[].City"
(Address is removed which is present after [].)

input => "Employee.Addresses[].Address.Lanes[].Lane.Name"
output => "Employee.Addresses[].Lanes[].Name"
(Address is removed which is present after []. and Lane is removed which is present after [].)
```

How to do this in C#?

Comment: what is "immediate"? what happens with multiple brackets? Question not clear at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private static IEnumerable<string> Filter(string input)
{
    var subWords = input.Split('.');
    bool skip = false;

    foreach (var word in subWords)
    {
        if (skip)
        {
            skip = false;
        }
        else
        {
            yield return word;
        }

        if (word.EndsWith("[]"))
        {
            skip = true;
        }
    }
}
```

And now you use it like this:

```
var filtered = string.Join(".", Filter(input));
```

Answer (score 1):

How about a regular expression?

```
Regex rgx = new Regex(@"(?<=\[\])\..+?(?=\.)");
string output = rgx.Replace(input, String.Empty);
```

Explanation:

```
(?<=\[\])            //positive lookbehind for the brackets
         \.          //match literal period
           .+?       //match any character at least once, but as few times as possible
              (?=\.) //positive lookahead for a literal period
```

Comment: this works, but the slashes need to be escaped, so you get something like this: `Regex rgx = new Regex("(?<=\\[\\])\\..*?(?=\\.)");`

Comment: The string is marked as a verbatim string literal, slashes are fine

Comment: @ColinM Actually not at the time of his comment.

Comment: Just noticed the edit history, the comment showed the `@` character when typing my comment, which was before the edit - strangely enough. No harm done

Answer (score 0):

Your description of what you need is lacking. Please correct me if I have understood it incorrectly.

You need to find the pattern `"[]."` and then remove everything after this pattern until the next dot `.`

If this is the case, I believe using a Regular Expression could solve the problem easily.

So, the pattern  `"[]."` can be written in a regular expression as 
`"\[\]\."`

Then you need to find everything after this pattern until the next dot: `".*?\."` (The `.*?` means every character as many times as possible but in a non-greedy way, i.e. stopping at the first dot it finds).

So, the whole pattern would be:

```
var regexPattern = @"\[\]\..*?\.";
```

And you want to replace all matches of this pattern with "[]." (i.e. removing what was match after the brackets until the dot).

So you call the [`Replace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7f5w83z(v=vs.110).aspx) method in the `Regex` class:

```
var result = Regex.Replace(input, regexPattern, "[].");
```